# How to insert subsection?

Tags: sectioning

Please, I want to add a `subsection` to the existing `section` in my `chapter 1`.  How can I do that? For example, I have `1.2.1` and I want to add `1.2.2`. How do I go about that?

Comment: Use `\subsection{}` below of some `\section{}` command.

Comment: You should rather read an introduction to LaTeX when you have to ask such questions.  Voting to close as duplicate of the book question.